# How do I display a pipe-separated string in dropdown box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting a string seperated with pipe. I want to show it in dropdown box. How can i achieve that?Asume the data i am getting is in this format

```
0123~Apple|Banana|Grapes|Oranges
```

Comment: `str.scan(/\w+/)[1..-1] => ["Apple", "Banana", "Grapes", "Oranges"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to get array of string:

```
str = "0123~Apple|Banana|Grapes|Oranges"
@options = str.split('~')[1].split("|") #=> ["Apple", "Banana", "Grapes", "Oranges"]
```

And to generate select tag use this:

```
<%= select_tag "xyz", options_for_select(@options) %>
```

Comment: Thanks Зелёный and Dipak it help me a lot.